# Net:HTTP timeout with Post class

Tags: ruby, http

I am trying to debug a web services issue, and have come across an interesting issue with Net:HTTP behaviour (no doubt my failure to understand how the Net::HTTP library should be used).

If I use the following, I get a response back from the server

```
require 'net/http'

USER='me'
PASS='me'
uri=URI('https://web.server.net/GetXMLData/webviewctl.asmx')

res=Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, 'action' => 'GetMyAssets', 'User' => USER, 'Password' => PASS)
```

Alternatively I could use an instantiated object of class Net::HTTP::Post rather than the class method - so the final line becomes:

```
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
req.set_form_data('action' => 'GetMyAssets', 'User' => USER, 'Password' => PASS)

res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) do |http|
   http.request(req)
end
```

However, this generates a read timeout:  `/home/steve/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb:158:in 'rescue in rbuf_fill': Net::ReadTimeout (Net::ReadTimeout)`

Does anyone have any thoughts on why this might be? What am I doing wrong in the second method. I'd prefer to use this as I can get finer control on what is actually sent to the server.

Thanks in advance

Steve

Comment: look here http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#attribute-i-read_timeout

Comment: Hi @Babai the second form is taken pretty much directly from the link you have posted, as an example of the use of Net::HTTP::Post

Comment: you can set the default time out,how to do so,is documented from the link.

Comment: Ok so the issue was that it was an https link, and I needed to set use_ssl. Thanks for the help